# check supportsDisplay in a function instead of within an intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a working skill that uses the function that checks whether the alexa device has a display so I can either build a template output or render output to a card:

```
function supportsDisplay() {
  var hasDisplay =
  this.event.context &&
  this.event.context.System &&
  this.event.context.System.device &&
  this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces &&
  this.event.context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.Display

  return hasDisplay;
}
```

I have a couple places where I render output so I wanted to make a function I can call to handle the visual output instead of having to rewrite the template code multiple times.

This returns an error. If I use this same function but comment out the call to the supportsDisplay function it works, so I assume the problem is in how I'm calling it:

```
function makeTemplate(playStatus){
if (supportsDisplay.call(this)){...}
return;
}
```

I also tried not making a function to check the display at all and actually just putting the code to check it directly in my function but that also didn't work.

I'm guessing part of the problem could be the this keyword (I'm very new to JS/Alexa dev and don't understand really what "this" does.

Is there a way to be able to call that supportsDisplay function from within my function? What would be the syntax do that?